# Does eating three to five whole eggs each day increase the level of blood cholesterol?

Tags: exercise, cholesterol

I am a great fan of eggs and have consumed many eggs a day since I was young.

I had not even the slightest worry about my blood cholesterol level until an old man told me yesterday about the detrimental effects that over eating eggs might have on my health.

**Does eating three to five whole eggs each day increase the level of blood cholesterol?**

Answer (score -2):

One egg contains about 186 mg of cholesterol, which is found mostly in the yolk. As with most foods, eggs should be eaten in moderation. Eggs can be a healthy food choice when you limit other foods with saturated and trans fat. A healthy person without high blood cholesterol can eat an average of one whole egg per day. This does not increase your risk for cardiovascular disease

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references/784#784)*. If you still have trouble with this, please feel free to visit the [help] or [meta].

Comment: Also can you elaborate?  What part of the egg contains cholesterol?  Does eating eggs increase HDL or LDL?